# filtering results using containsAllObjectsInArray

Tags: objective-c, search, nsarray, parse-platform

I am trying to filter results into a `searchDisplayController` by searching objects on parse.com. I can successfully search the objects and display them using containsString but that is not how I want to search the objects. I would like to search the objects using `containsAllObjectsInArray`. I don't know if I am going about this the correct way but anyway here's the code that I am trying:

```
- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {
NSCharacterSet *whitespaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSPredicate *noEmptyStrings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];
NSArray *parts = [searchTerm componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespaces];
NSArray *filteredArray = [parts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noEmptyStrings];
NSLog(@" filteredArray equals %@", filteredArray);

[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Items"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"itemName"];  
[query whereKeyExists:@"itemDescription"]; 
[query whereKey:@"itemName" containsAllObjectsInArray:filteredArray];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        for (PFObject *object in objects){

            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
            NSLog(@"%u", objects.count);   
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
            [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

In my output I am receiving the error:

```
code = 102;
error = "$all only works on array fields";
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work as filtered array is obviously an array and
the filtered array is being produced correctly in output.

Comment: Which line of code gives the error? The `PFQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` call?

Comment: Then I've updated your question, as the issue lies with Parse not `UISearchDisplayController`

Comment: @DavidCaunt Could you spare some time to help me with my problem please?

Comment: I've never worked with Parse, I'm afraid. Sorry. Your best bet is to try their support

Comment: Is "itemName" an array field? That's what the error is complaining about.

Comment: @HectorRamos thanks Hector that was my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are trying to search on a field that isn't an array (as the error states).

The `whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:` method means match any record where the field (an array) contains all elements in the supplied array.

e.g.:

```
Name: "Joe"
Moves: [ "Punch", "Kick", "Body Slam" ]

Name: "Jane"
Moves: [ "Punch", "Kick", "Eye Gouge" ]
```

Searching on the `Moves` field using an array containing "Punch" and "Kick" would match both records as both have those moves in their array. Searching on an array containing "Kick" and "Body Slam" would only match Joe.

If instead you are wanting to find records that contain a list of words in a string field, you would need to do a [whereKey:containsString:](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey%3acontainsString%3a) call for each word in your array, effectively an AND query.

Comment: Thanks your answer has helped me alot. Sorry to be annoying but can I ask for more help? I have not done anything like this before.

I am now using `[query whereKey:@"tags" containedIn:filteredArray];` 

How can I order the results to show the objects with the most matches at the top of my table?(for example if I searched "Punch","Eye Gouge" the results would be ordered Jane then Joe)

How can i make this a case insensitive search?

How can I search the objects so that if i search for "pun" instead of punch it will still show both Jane and Joe?

Comment: Or if you like I can mark your answer as correct and ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, best to ask that as a new question, so others can find it and benefit from it. I expect the best answer will be a mix of query and client-side manipulation.

Comment: In regards to matching partial tags, I would break that into two steps, first step make them pick a tag that matches the partial (e.g. if they enter "pu" offer "punch" and "push over" as options). Once you have complete tags then you can use `whereKey:containedIn:`.